# The Ringtone doesnt play, what is the Problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
  final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
                   
    timePickerDialog.updateTime(A1Stunde,A1Minute);
                timePickerDialog.show();
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, A1Stunde);
                        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, A1Minute);
                        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                         Uhrzeit = (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
    
                    if (currentTime+46803==Uhrzeit) {
                        r.play();
                        
                    }else{
                            r.play();
                           
                    }}
            },0,100);
```

//the if else statement works, i tried it with the log, but either if i have the r.play() in if or else it never plays any sound, what is the problem?

Comment: your r.play() will never called with this code because `currentTime +46803`never equals `uhrzeit`

Comment: it somehow did, thats what i meant with the if else statement works, i dont know why either. i just opened another question exactly about that because today the source code would have to be currentTime -39598 to work out.

Comment: what does number 39598 mean ?